# Произведение матриц Python

Tags: python, матрицы

Заданы две целочисленные матрицы A и B. Матрица A состоит из N строк и M столбцов, Матрица B состоит из M строк и P столбцов. Требуется вычислить произведение данных матриц A*B.
Входные данные
Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит три натуральных числа N, M и P. Далее следует описание матриц A и B. Матрица A состоит из N строк по M целых чисел. Матрица B состоит из M строк по P чисел. Матрицы отделены друг от друга пустой строкой. Все числа во входных данных не превышают 100 по абсолютной величине.
Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите матрицу, полученную в результате произведения A*B.

---

Мой код:

```
n, m, p = map(int, input().split())
X = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]

input()
Y = [list(map(int, input().split())) for j in range(m)]

result = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(X_row, Y_col)) for Y_col in zip(*Y)] for X_row in X]

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(p):
        print(result[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

---

Тестовые данные для ввода:
размерности 2 2 3

Матрица А

2 3

-1 4

Матрица Б

2 -3 4

3 1 0

Вывод:

13 -3 8

10 7 -4

Не могу найти решение для матриц разного размера, 2х2 на 2х3

Comment: Не понятно в чем именно вопрос. Как перемножать неквадратные матрицы?

Comment: Код оформляйте соответствующим образом. Непонятно - что именно мешает решать для других размеров - использование `zip(*Y)`?

Comment: Вопрос скорее как перемножить матрицы , размер которых вводит пользователь , т.е. они могут быть любого размера , мне тоже не понятно , пытался решить разными способами , может нужно вложенными циклами , я не знаю, я новичок в этом 
P.S. Извиняюсь за неудобное оформление

Comment: По сути должен, но загружаю ответ на сайт и выводит "Wrong Answer", задача взята с сайта acmp.ru
вот ссылка :
https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=8&id_topic=120&id_problem=747

Comment: в еще посмотрите здесь  http://matrixmultiplication.xyz/

Comment: спасибо за ссылку , в том то и проблема , я знаю как это делается на бумаге , но в коде туплю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При перемножении матриц указанных размеров получается матрица `n x p`.
Так что достаточно исправить при выводе

```
for i in range(n):
```

и код будет работать с любыми размерами

Если не использовать никаких питоновских штучек, кроме задания результирующей матрицы (так что циклы будут выглядеть так же в большинстве языков):

```
c = [[0]*p for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(p):
        for k in range(m):
            c[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]
```

Comment: Да , всё работает , большое спасибо , если не трудно , можете пожалуйста объяснить эту строчку ?

result = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(X_row, Y_col)) for Y_col in zip(*Y)] for X_row in X]

можно ли это по-другому написать , чтобы было более читабельно ?

Comment: Да,  это можно расписать  в три цикла прямо по [определению произведения матриц](https://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/Russian_sites/1/04.htm). Данный код берет поочередно строки из матрицы X, столбцы из матрицы Y (через zip(*Y)) и считает сумму их поэлементных произведений

Comment: можете , пожалуйста , написать как это будет выглядеть , если не тяжело , а то у меня небольшая проблема с пониманием какой цикл за каким следует и какой в какой вкладывается

Comment: @VladislavKlimenko Поскольку там внутренний цикл в квадратных скобках, то внешний цикл получается по `X`, а внутренний (следующий) по `Y`. Вот когда в списковом сокращении скобок внутри нет, а просто подряд идут `for`, то они идут именно в том порядке, в котором записаны. А тут не так.